# How to add middleware in grape?

Tags: ruby-grape

I need to add a middleware to grape like this:

```
class AfterFailure <  Grape::Middleware::Base

  def call!(env)
    @env = env
    before

    error = catch (:error) do 
      @app_response = @app.call(@env)
      return after || @app_response
    end

    after_failure(error) || throw(:error, error)   end

  def after_failure(error)
    puts "After Failure"

    nil   end

end
```

But I don't know how to add it to a api, How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. check the source code, found:

```
use AfterFailure
```